# can we align javascript ad code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The ad network I am using have JavaScript code so it is not aligning and breaking my site responsive I am able to align from the ad network who use the `<iframe>` tag but with these two ad network it is not aligning
I want my ads like this

```
[left ad]     [right ad]
```

but it goes like

```
[leftad]
[right]
```

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ylx-1.com/bnr.php?
section=General&pub=982769&format=300x250&ga=g"></script>
<noscript><a href="https://yllix.com/publishers/982769" target="_blank"><img 
src="//ylx-aff.advertica-cdn.com/pub/300x250.png" 
style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:baseline;" /></a>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
zone = "28";
pl = "442";
url = "https://uclick.in/network";
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uclick.in/network/show.js" >
</script>
```

I have tried align="right" and align: right; but they these both don't work

Comment: i have tried  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
zone = "28";
pl = "442";
url = "https://uclick.in/network";
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uclick.in/network/show.js" align="right">
</script>

Comment: also i have tried  
i have tried <script type="text/javascript"><!-- zone = "28"; pl = "442"; url = "uclick.in/network";; //--></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="uclick.in/network/show.js"; align:right;> </script>

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: with both of the ad codes one by one but nothing works , i also edit my question stack is not allowing me to add my full question :/

Comment: frankerZ when i am trying to state everything the stack keeps giving me error that you have not timed your correctly ....

Comment: Copy/paste the exact error you're getting

Comment: The `align` attribute is obsolete.

Comment: put the scripts inside of divs and align those.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts generate elements on the page. Style those elements rather than the script elements themselves. One possible solution to display the ads in a horizontal row is to [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) the generated `iframe` elements:

```css
iframe {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ylx-1.com/bnr.php?
section=General&pub=982769&format=300x250&ga=g"></script>
<noscript><a href="https://yllix.com/publishers/982769" target="_blank"><img 
src="//ylx-aff.advertica-cdn.com/pub/300x250.png" 
style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:baseline;" /></a>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  zone = "28";
  pl = "442";
  url = "https://uclick.in/network";
  //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uclick.in/network/show.js">
</script>
```

Comment: you have add the iframe css but i cant see where you have add the iframe tag in the code?

Comment: Each of the JavaScript scripts generates its own `<iframe>` element on the page. You can style those elements with CSS. For example, see the [source code](http://ylx-1.com/bnr.php?section=General&pub=982769&format=300x250&ga=g) for the first script: `document.writeln('<iframe`...